# How to call a javascript method from a href?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a side navigation menue with several menu items, each implemented as a href element, like:

`<li><span><a href="page.jsp">Href text</a></span></li>`

Each href calls a Jsp file with some functionality; in the browser the links looks active and correct: If the user moves the mouse cursor over the link, the mouse cursor changes to a hand with pointing finger.
The called Jsp page provides some input elements where the user can enter some data and click a send button. That works fine.

Now in one menu item I want the called Jsp page at once to show some data which I have to retrieve from a servlet; these data should not be requested by a click on a button in that page,
but be present at once when the page opens.

I have implemented that by:

`<li><span><a onClick="method(); return false;">Hfref text</a></span></li>`

So a javascript method is called when the user clicks the href; the method calls the servlet, gets the data and displays them, that works. The only missing point is that the menu item
seems to be inactive: When the user moves the mouse cursor on the menu item, the mouse cursor does not change. So a user would assume that the menu item text is not clickable.

I also tried:

`<li><span><a href="javascript:method()">Href text</a></span></li>`

This really calls my javascript method, but then that method cannot access the available HTML elements (it gets null when I call any document.getElementById("element"),
where the method find them if it is called via onClick=method.

How can I call a javascript method or a servlet from a href? Or how can I make a span with  have the same look and feel as a href?

Comment: In your first example simply include `href="javascript:void()"` and that will give you your active link.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from having a link (for appearance) and handling onclick on it instead of having a href. You can pass a href like "#" which gives the link the right appearance but at the same time does nothing. Then you can have an onclick on it

Comment: Yes, that works. And so easy!!! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in javascript but to my knowledge you can use `Document.GetElementById` to get that a tag and you can use the `onClick method`(in the `.js` file) so that when the `href` is called you can do whatever you want. if you still have problems pls tell me so I can tell you how to do this with code.

Answer (score 0):

Are you wanting to show a pointer with inline JS?

Here is one way with `onmouseover` - with this you can still keep your `onclick` function:

```html
<li><span><a onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'" onClick="method(); return false;">Href text</a></span></li>
```

Additionally, add styles to the link to make it more noticeable. Here I've made the link look like a button and I'm managing the style `onmouseout` as well.

```html
<li><span><a style="color: white; background-color: blue; padding: 10px; font-weight: bold;" onmouseover="this.style.cursor='pointer'; this.style.color='yellow'; this.style.backgroundColor='red';" onClick="method(); return false;" onmouseout="this.style.color='white';this.style.backgroundColor='blue';">Href text</a></span></li>
```

Comment: This doesnt help with `visited` and other text decoration styles. If you have no `href` defined on an anchor it wont display the `ua` specific style of anchors.

Comment: From my understanding, OP just wants the link to be more noticeable without losing the onClick functionality. He can control all of those ua specific styles by specifying them to his liking with hover states, event handling, and CSS.